# Missing 4 WFFM themes CSS Import Tags on CD Server

Tags: wffm

There seem to be 4 missing WFFM themes CSS import tags that are being display in our CM environment, but not in our CD environment.

I have verified that all 4 CSS files exist on the CD server. The problem is that there are no references to them in the head tags.

What could cause this? Is something not published?

Sitecore 7.5

**CM Environment:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the WFFM form was cached. After removing the cache setting the form works correctly.

The form would actually load correctly the first time the page was brought up, but it would submit back to itself and after that the CSS files were no longer included.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These files would not automagically make it from your CM to your CD server. Either the module package needs to be installed on each server using it (including your CD servers) or you would need to make sure the files from the package, becomes part of your conntinuous deployment routine (assuming you have one);.

Comment: I have verified that all 4 CSS files exist on the CD server. The problem is that there are no references to them in the head tags.